# webpages in subfolder not recognising styles

Tags: css

CSS is now working fine for the webpages in `bin` folder but Top header not appearing. The header file named **inner_header_new.html** is called on every page using a script like this:

```
# script should come here
```

This is working fine with the pages on root but not for webpages in `bin` folder. This header is located at the root of FTP:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <!-- header_main start -->
    <div class="inner_header_main">

      <!-- header_inner_main start -->
      <!-- <div class="header_inner_main"> -->

      <!-- header_top start -->
      <div id="inner_headerinclude"></div>
        <script>$('#inner_headerinclude').load('inner_header_new.html');</script>
```

Comment: Why you have put webpages in `bin` folder? Are you using `ASP.NET`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you dodn't post any code, we'll have to guess.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
```

Compare the two lines and check your own code.
Maybe you need this slash.

Answer (score 0):

If you request a nonexistent page Apache pulls up the 404 error page. However, apache does **not** redirect you to the 404 error page. Instead it pulls it up as though that was the page you were requesting. Since your stylesheet works at the root but not anywhere else, I can only presume that you used relative reference to your stylesheet instead of absolute.

Absolute referencing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ref="http://www.website.com/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
```

Or better yet:

```
<style type="text/css">
            @import url("/stylesheet.css");
        </style>
```

Try it out.

--
FYI - It is recommended to always use absolute referencing for your stylesheets. If you ever need to move the file to a different directory it won't break.

Comment: Why is the last one even better?

Comment: Not necessarily _better_, more convenient. You can use either method.